# What is the difference between the %PRId and %d format characters?

Tags: c, printf, conversion-specifier, length-modifiers

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

void main(void)
{
    int32_t a = 44;

    fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", a);
    fprintf(stdout, "%"PRId32"\n", a);
}
```

When is it better to use `%d` and when would it be better to use `"%"PRId32`? How do both of those format characters differ? Does this have something to do with how `int32_t` is typedeffed on your hardware/machine?

Comment: Note for C++ users looking at this question: `"%"PRId32` is fine in C, but for C++11 and later you need a space between, like `"%" PRId32`, or else `"%"PRId32` is a user-defined literal instead of two separate tokens, which will probably cause compile errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `%d` for `int` and `PRId32` for `int32_t`.

Maybe on your platform `int32_t` is just a typedef for `int` but this is not true in general.
Using a wrong specifier invokes undefined behavior and should be avoided.

As pointed out by @EricPostpischil note that `%d` is used inside a quoted format string while `PRId32` is used outside. The reason for this is that `PRId32` is a macro which expands to a string literal and is then concatenated.

Answer (score 4):

The type `int` is required to have at least 16 bits of value representation, although on most desktop computers and compilers it will have 32 bits.  So `int` might in general be the same as `int16_t`, `int32_t`, `int64_t`, or none of the above.

Use `"%d"` for variables of type `int`, and use `"%" PRId32` for variables of type `int32_t`.